# Time position in STFT output

Tags: stft, time-frequency

How can I understand in which time position in STFT function output am I?

For example, if I have 3987 time frame in the output of STFT, my window length is 625 (hamming), my hop size is 125 and the length of signal is 2 second.

- How can I estimate for example the first 5 milisecond or a window of 10 milisecond in the ouput of STFT? I know that the the number of time frames are calculated by

  ```
  coln = 1+fix((xlen-wlen)/h);
  ```
- But how is the equation in my situation?
- Can I say that each time frame has a length of hop size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [0-based vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), hop size $H$, and window size $M$, the frame number $N_f$ will contain the DFT of a window that starts on sample $n_1 = N_f \times H$ and ends on sample $n_2 = n_1 + M -1$.

That means that for each STFT frame, you shift the window by $H$ samples. Note that $H$ and $M$ not necessarily coincide.

Comment: Dear @Juancho, so, is it correct to say that each hop size equals the time frame lenght?